# How to encode unicode string into utf-8 string in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode

I'm trying to convert a unicode string to utf-8

I have been reading about python unicode handling and in python.

Python unicode how to says that I can do the following:

```
u.encode('utf-8')
```

where `u` is a unicode object.

I'm calling encode('utf-8') to a unicode object but the result is:

```
RemoteScriptError: LookupError
RemoteScriptError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
```

Do I need any special import or call to make python know how to encode the unicode object in utf-8?

Please note that i'm not using the system python. I'm inside a python 2.5 environment which seems to be builtin into the application I'm running this script.

When I need something that the built in python doesn't have I need to import it, for example struct.py

The application is Ableton Live which exposes the objects inside the application thru a python API. Ableton Live has tracks, clips, scenes, etc, which have a name property. That name property is a unicode object. I was using str(track.name) to get the string from the name, however it doesn't work with ç, á, í, characters...

In summary... what do I need to include, import or call, in order to have `.encode(encoding)` working?

Comment: Looks like Ableton Live's Python library is *incomplete*. Not much you can do about that, without codecs you cannot use `.encode()`. Have you tried the Ableton Live forums or file a bug report?

Comment: Yes, I have stated that it is incomplete. But I can also add files that I need to the script folder. Which files do I need in order to have encode support? I have digged into python source and there is the coders.py and the encodings dir couldn't do it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this: `import encodings`; that package registers the codec search function when imported. It may well be that that is missing though, in which case you need to copy it from a normal Python installation (`LIBDIR/python<version>/encodings/`)

Comment: In fact I have tried, not to copy the whole directory but only utf_8.py and codecs.py the following way: import codecs import utf_8
codecs.register(lambda encoding: utf_8.getregentry()) assert codecs.lookup("utf-8") however when doing u = unicode("blé") self.log(u.encode('utf-8')) it says 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That error is caused by something else; are you printing `u` too? Or are you concatenating unicode and a bytestring somewhere? The error is pointing to a *decode*, your code you shared is doing an encode instead.

Comment: Yes, i'm printing: self.log is printing the output of the encode. Let me just contextualize a bit more. The idea of all this is to transmit data from Ableton Live over network to another place. Basically i'm packaging messages with the struct pack. With pack I have s16 which will allow me to transfer 16 chars. This started to give problems when using accented chars. My idea is to pack the result of the encode as a normal string to the other side, where it will be interpreted according the encode I specify. Question, why does str(u.encode('utf-8')) does not work?

Comment: I confess that I have always ignored this encoding things until now!!

Comment: Read up on the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) in that case. For interprocess communication, consider using JSON or even pickle instead; easier to deal with variable-length data that way.